# C programming segmentation error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is the code for finding the last digit of nth Fibonacci number

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long i, j, fib[1000];
    fib[0] = 0;         
    fib[1] = 1;         

    scanf("%li", &j);     

    for(i = 2; i != 1000; i++)     
    {
        fib[i] = (fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1]) % 10;
    }
    printf("%li", fib[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

It shows segmentation fault. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have removed the `c++` tag since this question is about C.

Comment: What is the purpose of `j`?

Comment: which line does it show the segmentation fault on? run your code in a debugger and it should tell you and then you can flesh out your question

Comment: @SouravGhosh `j` is the "n" in "nth fibionacci no."

Comment: It works fine or me, and I don't see much wrong with it.  Are you sure the code you posted is exactly the same as what you're running?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are off by one on the input? With the current code you need to input `n-1` to get the nth number. Valid input is `0` to `999` and input `1000` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `% 10`?

Comment: If `j >= 1000`, the last `printf()` statement has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelWalz OP wants to find the last digit of a Fibonacci number. Something like `fibnum % 10` does that nicely.

Comment: regarding this expression: `i != 1000;` in the `for()` loop statement.  in C, the offset into an array starts with 0 and ends with `number of items in array -1`  and the array is declared as: `int ... fib[1000];`  so the max offset is 999, not 1000.  So the for statement should be: `for( i=2; i<1000; i++)`  The current code is accessing beyond the end of the array.  Such access is undefined behavior and can/will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: the posted code has a serious logic error.  It does not verify that the value read from the user is within the range of valid offsets into the array `fib[]`  In general, the code should prompt the user as to what the user is expected to do.  Otherwise when the user runs the code, all they will see is a blank screen with a blinking cursor and no idea as to what to do next

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, the returned value must be 1 otherwise a error has occurred.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   The compiler doesn't care, but the human reader does care about readability.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  I.E. 1000  Suggest using a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the posted code does NOT place the fib values into the array, so each successive calculation (after the first few) is not correct

Comment: the posted code displays the wrong entry in the array of 'fib's, it is off-by-1

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see for this not working is that you're inputting a number that is outside of the range `0 <= j <= 999`. This is due to the limit on your array variable: `long fib[1000]`.

This can be fixed in one of two ways, depending on what you want:

1. You can add a check to make sure that the input value `j` is in range, and ask for another number if it isn't.
2. You can stop using an array variable, and only use three variables: one to store the current value, and two more to store the two previous values. These are updated as you calculate. A loop is still used with this approach.

#1 is the simplest to implement, as shown here:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("j > ");
    scanf(" %li", &j);

    if (0 <= j <= 999)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

#2 is a bit more complex, but it effectively removes the arbitrary limit that `j` must be less than 1000 (and changes the limit so that `j` must be less than `LONG_MAX`):

```
// num_cache[0] is the number before the previous number
// num_cache[1] is the previous number to the current number
long num_cache[2] = { 0, 0 };
long current_fib = 1;

for (i = 2; i < j; i++)
{
    // Push back the numbers
    num_cache[0] = num_cache[1];
    num_cache[1] = current_fib;

    // Calculate the new number
    current_fib = (num_cache[0] + num_cache[1]) % 10;
}
```

One of those solutions should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the segmentation fault is occurring due to inadequate checking of input values.

1. If the input to the program is not a valid number, then the value of `j` will be unchanged after the call to `scanf()`. Since this variable is uninitialized, this will result in undefined behaviour when you attempt to access the jth element of the `fib[]` array.
2. If the value of j is less than zero or greater than 999, you will be accessing a non-existent member of `fib[]` when you exit the `for()` loop. Your code should check that `j` is valid before continuing.

Here's your code with a few modifications to implement these safeguards and move the "magic number" 1000 to a #defined value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FIBONACCI_LIMIT 1000L

int main(){
  long i, j, fib[FIBONACCI_LIMIT];
  fib[0] = 0;
  fib[1] = 1;
  if (scanf("%li", &j) != 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if (j<0 || j>=FIBONACCI_LIMIT)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Number must be in range 0 <= n < %li\n", FIBONACCI_LIMIT);
    return 2;
  }
  for(i=2; i!=1000; i++)
  {
    fib[i] = (fib[i-2] + fib[i-1])%10;
  }
  printf("%li\n", fib[j]);
  return 0;
}
```

The code can be improved by getting rid of the `fib[]` array altogether, since there is no need to store 1000 values when you only need to calculate one value. Furthermore, the final digits of numbers in the Fibonacci sequence form a repeating pattern of 60 values, so your first step should be to replace `j` with `j % 60`. Here is an improved version of the code that will work with any non-negative input capable of fitting into a `long` integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long i, j, t, f0=0, f1=1;
  if (scanf("%li", &j) != 1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
    return 1;
  }
  if (j < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Number must be non-negative\n");
    return 2;
  }
  j %= 60;
  for (i=0; i<j; i++)
  {
    t = f0;
    f0 = f1;
    f1 = (f1 + t) % 10;
  }
  printf("%li\n", f0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not show what value of the variable `j` was entered.

Take into account that the next Fibonacci number is calculated incorrectly in the loop.

If to use the integer type `unsigned long long` then an object of this type can accommodate only 93 Fibonacci numbers.

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   100

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned long long fib[N] = { 0, 1 };

        unsigned int n;

        printf( "Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): " );
        if ( scanf("%u", &n) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        unsigned int i = 2;
        for (; i < N && i <= n && fib[i-1] <= fib[i-2] + fib[i-1]; i++)
        {
            fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
        }

        if (n < i)
        {
            printf("#%u: %llu %llu\n", n, fib[n], fib[n] % 10);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Too big fibonacci number");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): 1
#1: 1 1
Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): 2
#2: 1 1
Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): 3
#3: 2 2
Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): 93
#93: 12200160415121876738 8
Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): 94
Too big fibonacci number
Enter a sequantial number of a fibonacci number (0 - exit): 0
```